# Example of orthogonal dependent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I would like to confirm with an example that I get what the definition of orthogonality of two random variables means, as defined in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/16315/67822):

$$\mathbb E[XY^*]=0$$

It's [not the first time I ask about this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2002043/152225), but in the current post I'd like to ask for an example of the statement

> If $Y=X^2$ with symmetric pdf they are dependent yet orthogonal.

Can we then proof that for a normal standard deviation $X \sim N(0,1)$ - perfectly symmetrical - and $Y=X^2$ (which will have a [pdf as in here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/953566/152225)), the $\mathbb E[XY^*=0]$?

Comment: Aren't $X$ and $Y$ real? What is $Y^*$?

Comment: Yes, they are. It is the general definition as in the referenced post (first link).

Comment: I erased the formula. Your comment makes sense, and the formula was just a quick attempt at showing how I would start thinking about the problem. It is not homework.

Comment: Note to self: [this is a good entry](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/312616/152225) to understand the operations behind this in the discrete case. And for inner product, [this is a great one](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1414403/152225).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works explicitly for the situation as stated in the question. Since $Y=X^2$ we have $XY = X^3$. Since $X$ is standard normal distributed, it's pdf 
$$ f_X(x) = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}2 \right) $$ 
is symmetric around $0$, that is an even function. Thus, we have

$$E(XY) = E(X^3) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \underbrace{\underbrace{\phantom{f}x^3}_{\text{odd}} \underbrace{f_X(x)}_{\text{even}}}_{\text{odd}} dx = 0.$$

Remember that the integral of any (integrable) odd function $g$ is zero, as:
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g(x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g(-x) \, |-1| dx = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} -g(x) dx = -\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g(x) dx. $$

Comment: @AntoniParellada: It has nothing to do with homework or not. What remains unclear to you? I will add more details.

Comment: I read your comment about independence, which makes sense. I don't see then how you set up the equation in your post as the E[XY]. I wrote the equation in my OP to show a bit what I had in mind, but without conviction. Also, I'd like to see the resolution applied to the normal distribution.

Comment: Just replace $f_X(x)$ by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$, then.

Comment: There is no multiplication of pdf's. Do you agree that if $Y=X^2$, then $XY=X^3$? And therefore that $\mathbb{E}[XY]=\mathbb{E}[X^3]$?

Comment: Yes, I follow this part well. But after that, is the formula as you set it up an inner product? What is the set up for the formula? I see that the definition is $E[XY]$, but I thought, from my previous question that this was a bit more complicated than multiplying the random variables, and using the pdf of $X$ to integrate.

Comment: @AntoniParellada: It is the definition of pdf that $E(\phi(X)) = \int_\mathbb R \phi(x) f_X(x) dx$ holds for every borel measurable function $\phi:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$.

Comment: ... LOTUS strike again?

Comment: @AntoniParellada: pardon?

Comment: [LOTUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) = Law of the Unconscious Statistician. OK. Now I see it. And I appreciate your help (+1).

Comment: @AntoniParellada the definition part refers to $f_X \, dx = dF_X$ not the transformation with $\phi$ part :p

Comment: Can you clarify your last comment?

Comment: @AntoniParellada it is just a joke. You are right, that expected value formula isn't the definition of a PDF.

Comment: I am reading this as the expectation of the inner product of the pdf's of $X$ and $Y$. Now the [inner product of two continuous functions](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1414403/152225) (pdf's) involves an integral, and the $\mathbb E[\cdot]$ of a continuous random variable (now $XY$) also includes an integral. This latter integral is there, while the inner product is reduced to $X^3$... I know your post is correct, but I wonder if you could insert a sentence linking the idea of inner product and the first $XY=X^3$ expression. Is it the inner product?

Comment: @AntoniParellada: remember that random variables are just functions. The overly formal way is: $E(XY) = \int_\Omega X(\omega) Y(\omega)  \, dP(\omega) = \int_\Omega X(\omega) X^2(\omega)  \, dP(\omega) = \int_\Omega X^3 (\omega) \, dP(\omega) = \int_\mathbb R x^3 f_X(x) \, dx$.